# Razor Generating Html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

my razor code

```
@Html.CheckBox("cbMSSProvider",true)
```

is generating HTML like

```
    <input checked="checked" id="cbHHAProvider" name="cbHHAProvider" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input name="cbHHAProvider" type="hidden" value="false">
```

Can some one tell why there is input(type=hidden)?

Comment: Read [ask] and try searching before asking a new question.

Comment: The hidden field is used to for sending the field name to the server if it was checked, if was not checked then the field does not go to the server and the value of the model will be false

Answer (score -2):

MVC is an open source project. You can delve into the code yourself if you want to understand how they work and/or ask questions about their decision making process.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc

So to answer your question, why it does that, it's because how it's implemented.